# HTML5 Video click event for closed captions?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm creating a custom video player using the `<video>` html5 tag.

Currently I'm accessing the `video.pause()` and `video.play()` methods to control playback. There are further controls within the controls attribute such as "Closed Captions".

I can access the object like so:  `video.textTracks[0].mode` however, what I would like is to add a click event to toggle the captions displaying on or off.

Is this possible? Looking through docs under available methods it doesn't seem so: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

I'm currently doing this with the pause and play methods available on the video HTMLVideoElement like so:

```
 const handleMouseEnter: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLVideoElement> = () => {
    setIsHover(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLVideoElement> = () => {
    setIsHover(false);
  };

  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLVideoElement> = (event) => {
    const video = event.target;

    if (video && video instanceof HTMLVideoElement) {
      console.log('video :>> ', video.textTracks[0].mode.toString());
      if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        setPlay(true);
      } else {
        video.pause();
        setPlay(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

Useage:

```
<video
  className={`cursor-pointer ${className}`}
  onClick={handleClick}
  onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
  onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
  controlsList={'nodownload noremoteplayback'}
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
>
  <track src={captions} kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="English" />
  <source src={url} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an way to do it - hope this helps someone in future.

```
const handleCaptions: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLImageElement> = () => {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');

    if (video instanceof HTMLVideoElement && video.textTracks[0].mode === 'disabled') {
      setPlayerCaptions('showing');
      video.textTracks[0].mode = 'showing';
    } else if (video instanceof HTMLVideoElement && video.textTracks[0].mode === 'showing') {
      setPlayerCaptions('disabled');
      video.textTracks[0].mode = 'disabled';
    }
  };
```

Usage:

```
<Image
  src={CaptionsSVG}
  width={170}
  height={170}
  alt="Captions"
  className="caption absolute bottom-0 right-0 z-10 cursor-pointer"
  priority={true}
  onClick={handleCaptions}
/>
```